Draw fold-line path between two node
I have to archive something like blew:

There are two nodes and the source node have an output point need to connect to target node's input point. The line should be straight fold line.
I know we can easily calculate the path when the target node right beside source node like
<path d="M $(oldxx) $(oldyy) L $(xx) $(yy)" fill="transparent" stroke="black"/>,
but the hard thing is, all source node and target node has it own width and height, so there will be some complicated situation like belows: 

Target node befor source node. 


Target node nearly overlap the source node and there is no space beside for drawing the line, the line need be surround those two nodes. 



You can try this graph here https://gojs.net/beta/samples/logicCircuit.html
Is there any open source algorithm can calculate the path string for this?
Currently we use d3 to draw the node, is there any method for d3 to accomplish this?
For more information, seems the tangled tree in d3 can draw this line, but i'm not sure how to dynamic update the line when dragging.
